# Slick Slider Syncing with Lazy Load

Tags: carousel, lazy-loading, slick.js, web-performance, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to optimize my Slick gallery using Lazy Load. However I haven't been able to run lazy load on a carousel with slider syncing. Chrome DevTools Network shows that all images are being loaded despite I added `lazyLoad: 'ondemand'`.

Here's an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/retroriff/m9h6vsz3/6/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just removing `fade: true`. Now I have been able to ladyload all images but the last one. For some reason if you have 10 pictures, pic num 10 is loaded.